# Post method in Ionic returns 404

Tags: angularjs, post, ionic-framework

I have problem implementing post method in a service based on a REST architecture.
All get methods are working properly, but when I run post I get status 404.

I want to send list of integers. 
I'm using factories to provide methods and use them in controllers

**service file**

```
 angular.module('groups.services', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'constants'])
    .factory('Group', function ($resource, MAIN) {
      return {
        getGroupStudents: function () {
          return $resource(MAIN.url + '/student?groupId=:groupId');
        },
        saveTimesheet: function () {
          return $resource(MAIN.url + '/timesheet', null, {
            save: {
              method: 'POST',
              isArray: true
            }
          }, {headers: {"Content-Type": 'application/json'}});
        }
      }
    });
```

**controller**

```
 angular.module('groups.controller', ['groups.services'])
     .controller('GroupCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, Group) {
           var presence = [];

           $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
               presence = [];
           });

           $scope.students = Group.getGroupStudents().query({groupId: $stateParams.groupId});

           $scope.checkTimesheet = function () {
              $state.transitionTo('app.timesheet', {'groupId': $stateParams.groupId});
           };

           $scope.addToPresenceList = function (student) {
              if (student.checked) {
                 presence.push(student.id);
              } else {
                 var index = presence.indexOf(student.id);
                 presence.splice(index, 1);
              }
           };

           $scope.saveTimesheet = function () {
                 Group.saveTimesheet().save({ "studentIds": presence});
           };

       });
```

**api on server side (java + jersey)**

```
@Path(TimesheetWebApi.BASE_PATH)
public interface TimesheetWebApi {

    public static final String BASE_PATH = "/timesheet";

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response saveTimesheet(@NotNull List<Integer> studentIds);
}
```

**request payload**

```
{studentIds: [1, 2]}
```

**request**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8100/app/timesheet
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8100
```

Any hint? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try to post using Postman or any other rest client and see if it works fine?

Comment: Yes, I did that too and also gets 404

Comment: So, I think that the URL is wrong.

Comment: Just found the problem... It wasn't the URL but I forgot to register bean on the server side. However your comment made me to think so thank you ;)

It's wierd though, that Eclipse didn't throw any exception. I thought I get some errors in the past when I forgot to register a bean...

Comment: Nice to know that you solved it. Please, create an answer with your solution and accept it for order purpose. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a missing bean registration on the server side.

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath(JerseyConfig.APPLICATION_PATH)
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    static final String APPLICATION_PATH = "/app";

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(TimesheetWebApiImpl.class);
    }
}
```